# Where does the C++ standard state that subobjects of an array declared as static are static objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, static, language-lawyer

Given the following code ([it compiles successfully](https://godbolt.org/z/xq8o6ssd1)):

```
int main(void)
{
  const int a{};
  const int &r = a;
  static int arr[1] = {r};
  constexpr const int &ref = arr[0]; // OK
}
```

The initialization of `ref` is glvalue designating reference `ref`. So the full-expression of the initialization has to be a glvalue core constant expression. That's, the reference `ref` has to refer to an entity that's a [permitted result of a constant expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#def:constant_expression,permitted_result_of) (object with static storage duration). It refers to the element `arr[0]` which is of type `int`. Here's my question: Is this element a subobject with static storage duration? if yes, what's the wording that states that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here's my question: Is this element a subobject with static storage duration?

[[basic.stc.inherit]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.stc.inherit) says:

> The storage duration of subobjects and reference members is that of their complete object.

An array element is a subobject of the array it is an element of. So it has the same storage duration as the array.